# Is there better way to retrieve multiple CURSOR from StoredProc to Java?

Tags: java, database, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

I have a solution to retrieve DB2 cursors from a stored procedure but I am looking for a better approach. The current solution looks like described below:-

**Stored Proc:-**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc(c1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, c2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
         c3 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, ....)
is
BEGIN
  open c1 FOR select feild1,feild2,.... from RSPNSE_TABLE1;
  open c2 FOR select feild1,feild2,.... from RSPNSE_TABLE2;      
  open c3 FOR select feild1,feild2,.... from RSPNSE_TABLE3;
  open c4 FOR select feild1,feild2,.... from RSPNSE_TABLE4;
  open c5 FOR select feild1,feild2,.... from RSPNSE_TABLE5;
  // continue this i got least 30 tables
END;
```

**The java code** to retrieve these cursors which looks like this:-

```
public boolean callProc() throws Exception {
       Connection conn = openConnection();
       CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;

       int rowCount = 0;
       try {

            String proc = "call Proc(?,?,?,?,.....)";
            callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(proc);

            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, DB2Types.CURSOR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, DB2Types.CURSOR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, DB2Types.CURSOR);
            .....
            .....

            boolean results = callableStatement.execute();

            rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
            // retrieve data from resultset                             
            rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);
            // retrieve data from resultset
            ......
            ......      

        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw e;
        }
        return true;
}
```

I have following questions about this,

1. Is there batter way to return multiple cursors from DB2 Proc ?
2. If so then what is java code to retrieve it from callable statement ?

**Note:** Individual answer for both is excepted. Even pointing out to right resources where I can read and achieve is also excepted.

Comment: Have you tried the manual? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvjdmlt.html?lang=en

Comment: @mustaccio I will try that after i will find out how to return multiple result set from proc. Do you know how can i do that ?

Comment: Why do you want multiple cursors?  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I am trying to return multiple queries to reduce individual query parsing back and forth between jdbc and database.

Comment: @JBaba - what I'm getting at is, why are you doing this as multiple statements, instead of as one?  Should some (all?) of the results be `JOIN`ed into one statement?  Or are things too unrelated?  From a quick perusal of the documentation, this is the way you'd get/use multiple cursors.